# CORS error after deployment of the application to Vercel

Tags: node.js, cors, backend, fetch-api, vercel

I am trying to send a GET request from my frontend (ReactJs) to my backend (Nodejs) on page load using the useEffect hook. This request carries credentials to authenticate the user using the JSON Web Token contained in the Http Only cookies.

The fetch request in frontend:-

```
const res = await fetch(url.url + "page", {
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
        })

        const data = await res.json()

        if (data.status === "invalid") {
            window.location = url.client + "login"
        }
```

Middlware used in my backend:-

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "www.example.com",
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
}
```

This fetch request works perfectly fine in my local environment. I look for the response headers in the network tab and they work as intended. However, when I deploy the backend to Vercel, I get the following error:-

```
Access to fetch at 'http://backend.app/page' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

I tried putting the headers in vercel.json:-

```
"headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "www.example.com" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This is a screenshot of the response headers that I get after deployment on Vercel, the origin header has a wildcard ("*") despite me assigning the origin in the response header. This is the main cause of the problem (I think):-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8NS8.png)

Response headers when I deploy locally, you can see that headers are as expected:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noJeO.png)

So what can I try to fix this problem? I have tried searching for things to change in vercel.json, like putting the headers object inside routes object, but to no avail. Please help me.

Sorry if I sound vague, or if there's not enough/improper info for the problem I am having. This is my first post here :)

Comment: `www.example.com` is not a valid Web origin. Did you mean `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: @jub0bs Yea my bad. I replaced the original names with dummies. You could ssume I have the original names there instead of "https://backend" and "https://example.com"